# How to Apply Pagination for Relational table access in Entity Framework core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Before asking my question I provided the return JSON.

```
  "story": [
{
    "storyId": 47,
    "storyName": "some story",
    "storyShortDescription": "some story",
    "isActive": true,
    "episodes": [
        {
            "episodeId": 13,
            "episodeName": "42 - Sulanga nuba saha mama",
            "episodeShortDescription": "some්data .",
            "episodeCoverImageUrl": "https://scontent.fcmb3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/118338006_800506980776518_4147171092731609418_n.jpg?_nc_cat=103&_nc_sid=825194&_nc_ohc=8Hdp7Bpjb9cAX-VitoO&_nc_ht=scontent.fcmb3-1.fna&oh=edce9d9908efc6fbfcb70c3fec1cc7fb&oe=5F766E96",
            "episodeContent": "sone data",
            "storyId": 47
        },
        {
            "episodeId": 13,
            "episodeName": "42 - Sulanga nuba saha mama",
            "episodeShortDescription": "some්data .",
            "episodeCoverImageUrl": "https://scontent.fcmb3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/118338006_800506980776518_4147171092731609418_n.jpg?_nc_cat=103&_nc_sid=825194&_nc_ohc=8Hdp7Bpjb9cAX-VitoO&_nc_ht=scontent.fcmb3-1.fna&oh=edce9d9908efc6fbfcb70c3fec1cc7fb&oe=5F766E96",
            "episodeContent": "sone data",
            "storyId": 47
        },
         {
            "episodeId": 13,
            "episodeName": "42 - Sulanga nuba saha mama",
            "episodeShortDescription": "some්data .",
            "episodeCoverImageUrl": "https://scontent.fcmb3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/118338006_800506980776518_4147171092731609418_n.jpg?_nc_cat=103&_nc_sid=825194&_nc_ohc=8Hdp7Bpjb9cAX-VitoO&_nc_ht=scontent.fcmb3-1.fna&oh=edce9d9908efc6fbfcb70c3fec1cc7fb&oe=5F766E96",
            "episodeContent": "sone data",
            "storyId": 47
        }
    ]
}
```

]
}

So, here I want to Paging Episode part. How should I change my query to do that?

here I added the query.

```
 var episodeList = _context.Story.Where<Story>(story => story.storyId == storyId).Include(auther => auther.auther).Include(episode => episode.episodes).Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList()[0];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below query:

```
var episodeList = _context.Story
    .Where<Story>(story => story.storyId == storyId)
    .Include(episode => episode.episodes)
    .SelectMany(x => x.Episodes.Skip(index).Take(size))
    .ToList();
```

**Update:**

If you want to return the story type, you can use the below linq:

```
var result = (from s in _context.Story
                    where s.StoryId == storyId
                    join e in _context.Episodes on s.StoryId equals e.StoryId
                    select new
                    {
                        Story = s,
                        Episodes = s.Episodes.ToList().Skip(skip).Take(take)
                    }).FirstOrDefault().Story;
```

I made a test based on your codes:

**dbo.Story**

[image]

**dbo.Episodes**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: It's changed my return JSON Strucher.

Comment: Hi @NaminduSanchila I have updated my answer,you can have a check.

Comment: I am so glad to you your effort put on this. thank you very much. :
0